# Apache prepend URL before requested URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I retrieve a URL like this:

```
http://xxx.example.com/resource/blahblah
```

and rewrite this address

```
http://example.com/yyy/zzz/vvv.html?subject=http://xxx.example.com/resource/blahblah
```

by Apache server and using mod-rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the question has a negative point!! And I don't know why the answers are such irrelevant. Anyway, I have found the true answer by myself.

Create a file in this path or edit that file:

```
sudo nano /var/www/html/.htaccess
```

Fill the file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# avoids recursive rewrite of scripts
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  ^http://xxx\.example\.com/.*$
RewriteRule ^yyy/.* - [L]

# rewrites scripts and css files
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  ^http://xxx\.example\.com/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ yyy/$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^resource/([^\/]*)$ yyy/zzz/vvv.html?subject=http://xxx.example.com/resource/$1 [QSA]
```

and restart apache service:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

save the contents of url. Then upload the index.html page on apache server and start the apache server .

Comment: I want to use mod-rewrite, I can't save all of my 6000000 urls in html files!

Comment: mod_rewrite is used for rewriting a URL. For example **www.xyz.com/login/sahil** is converted to **www.xyz.com/login.html?name=sahil**